# My Post function not working with Postman heres in MonogDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

To start with I am noob in node.js and MongoDb and working with tutorial with Lama Dev social media as a basic project kindly help

in Postman
error 404 is coming
where in the video it's 200 ok
I have copied main code for 100-1000 times help

**This Is my auth.js file**

```js
//auth.js 
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");

//register
router.post("/register", async (req, res) =>{
    const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    });

    try{
        const user = await newUser.save();
        res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**This Is my User.js file in models folder**

```js
//User.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    min: 3,
    max: 20,
    unique: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 50,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 6,
  },
  profilePicture: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  coverPicture: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  followers: {
    type: Array,
    default: [],
  },
  followings: {
    type: Array,
    default: [],
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**This Is my index.js file**

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const morgan = require("morgan");

const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");

dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, ()=> {
    console.log("MongoDb Connected");
});

//middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);

app.listen(8800, ()=>{
    console.log("Backhend server is running");
})
```

**And this is a screenshot of postman**

[Postman ScreenShot Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFiVl.png)

Comment: You have not selected post method in postman.

Answer (score 1):

Your POSTMAN screenshot shows your HTTP verb being `GET`, but the route your registered is using `POST`. Try changing the verb in POSTMAN.